# Running parallel stages on node with one executor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Suppose that I have one jenkins node with one executor and I have to run i.e. tests and build stages in parallel.

```
node("jenkinsNodeWithOneExecutor") {

    parallel {
        test: {echo "run test" ... }
        build: {echo "run build" ...}
    }

}
```

How this will work? In the logs I see that that it runs parallel. Is it possible? I thought that every parallel task needs own executor...

PS. When trying to run job twice: Waiting for next available executor on ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a job in parallel the job will branch off and create two different jobs which will (ideally) execute simultaneously.

In your example you'd actually have three jobs: the original job, the "test" job, and the "build" job. You would need three executors available to process the script in parallel. If you're running the initial job on the same node you're trying to run parallel jobs on and you only have one executor this job would always hang indefinitely waiting for an executor that will never be available. If you're running the original job on another node it'd process your jobs sequentially since you only have one executor.

Are you sure you want to run your tests in parallel with your build? Typically tests have a dependency on whatever you've built. This would run the tests at the same time as the build and your build artifacts may not be available yet.

Comment: thanks! test and build stage is an example, of course it will be not executed in parallel :) so according to your answer, is there a possibility that something is blocking concurrent builds when trying to run job twice on the same node but running stages in parallel inside one jenkinsfile works? I know it sounds weird, but it works in that way...

Comment: When using pipelines you tell Jenkins which stages can be parallelized. It's then up to Jenkins to figure out how to actually distribute the job based on the rules you've put in place. If you don't have enough executors in place to actually perform steps in parallel Jenkins will serialize the steps. In the same vein it is entirely possible to deadlock jobs especially if you're building multiple times. It's up to you to set rules in your pipelines and environment to prevent deadlocks.